# Identifying Window Latch

Tags: windows, latches

I would appreciate it if anybody could tell me what type of window latch is in the picture below?

I bought a house and need to change a couple of these that are broken.

Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sash lock **or** [casement window sash lock](https://www.pwdservice.net/Crestline-Vetter-Peachtree-Series-500-Casement-Window-Sash-Lock-White).

[duckduckgo](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=casement%20window%20sash%20lock&t=ffsb&iar=images&iax=images&ia=images&iai=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.homedepot.com%2Fcatalog%2FproductImages%2F1000%2F87%2F8797d826-da43-4a0c-99e5-88758c08a6b0_1000.jpg)

I have seen them at the home improvement stores.

I call them a pain in the ***